# How do you border-bottom:none; the previous menus?

Tags: html, css

So I've created a menu using flex.
I am using bottom borders when a menu isn't hovered to indicate that their are items a user can select when they hover their mouse on the menu.

When a user hovers on a menu I want to erase bottom borders on the other menus which the user hasn't hovered their mouse at.

My code can erase the bottom borders of the menus that are after hovered menu.

Problem: My code can't erase the bottom borders of the menus that are before the hovered menu.

JSfiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Hiroga/pubLdtxh/

CSS:

```
/*
    ColorCombo Ref:http://www.colorcombos.com/color-schemes/107/ColorCombo107.html
    #6699CC
    #003366
    #C0C0C0
    #000044
*/

body {
    background-color:#000044;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

/*Navigation*/
nav {
    display:flex;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:5px 5px 5px;
}

nav > div {
    margin:5px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border-radius:5px;
}

.menu{
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
}

.menu > div {
    display:none;
}

.menu:hover{
    border-bottom:none;
}

.menu:hover ~.menu{
    border-bottom:none;
}

.menu:hover > div{
    display:flex;
    margin-top:3px;
    background-color:#C0C0C0;
    border-radius:5px;
    justify-content:center;
    align-content:center;
}

.menu:hover > div:first-child {
    border-top:3px solid black;
}

.menu:hover > div:last-child {
    border-bottom:3px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Sample Modern</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <div>
            Home
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            Menu
            <div>
                Item
            </div>
            <div>
                Item
            </div>
            <div>
                Item
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            Menu 2
            <div>
                Item 2
            </div>
            <div>
                Item 2
            </div>
            <div>
                Item 2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            Menu 3
            <div>
                Item 3
            </div>
            <div>
                Item 3
            </div>
            <div>
                Item 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Providing fiddle helps up to understand your question better.

Comment: Mmm what's fiddle? Wait I'll check it out.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ make a demo here

Comment: Roger that I'll do that

Comment: Okay I just added the fiddle link thanks btw for the tip ^_^

Comment: Hey @GianPatrick your description is little confusing. Not getting the requirement. What you need actually?

Comment: @KushalJayswal I fixed the description I think it should be better now.

Comment: check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s3zwh0an/1/ , is this is what you are looking for

Comment: @Mehavel Yeah, that works too, instead of making them disappear.

Comment: doing this with pure css seems to be impossible, atleat until css4 with parent selector arrives. Untill then javascript is there for your rescue.

Comment: @Mehavel You're answer was actually perfect I was waiting for you to post it as the answer XD.

Comment: @GianPatrick stackoverflow taught to keep discussions as comments. Hence the delay in posting it as answer :)

Comment: @GianPatrick, have you checked my answer below? Does it match with your expectation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing this with pure css seems to be impossible, atleast until css4 with parent selector arrives. Untill then javascript is there for your rescue. If you would like a CSS solution, which will still not hide the previous element border,but make the border not expand look the solution below

I have created a fiddle with the inputs you have given. View the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/s3zwh0an/1/)

- Added `<span>` tag for each menu item
- Added `border-bottom` to `.menu span`
- Added css to remove the border-bottom of `<span>` element on hover

  **CSS Addition :**

  ```
   .menu span{
        border-bottom:3px solid black;
      }

   .menu:hover >span{
       border-bottom:none;
     }
  ```

hope this helps

Comment: I have posted this as answer only after the user accepted it as a a solution in comments. If you are downvoting, leave a comment on what can be improved

Answer (score 3):

#### View this Live <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pubLdtxh/1/)</kbd>

Add this,

```
.menu:not(:active){
    border-bottom:none;
}
```

Comment: That one just erased all my bottom borders when it isn't hovered. I need the bottom borders when it isn't hovered to indicate that you can hover to it to indicate that there are items the user can select when he hovers.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I got description clearly now.

I think you need to use sort of script here.
Kindly look on below code snippets.

**Script**

```
$('nav .menu').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

**CSS Addition**

```
nav > .menu.active{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pubLdtxh/3/)